# Bullets of unordered list won't display

Tags: joomla-3.4, templates, css, joomla-3.5, gavick

Can someone please tell me why bullets won't work?

Whenever, I Bullet a list it doesn't appear on my web page.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing / doing wrong?

Cheers

Carlton

Comment: The strange thing is when I click 'Preview' I can see the bullets, but I can't see the bullets after I've published the webpage...

Comment: Perhaps sharing a link to your site so we can inspect the code would help?

Comment: I'd imagine it's your template's css.  Try applying a different template to the page and see if it's still an issue.

Comment: Richard, you're correct. It's my templates css. Can you please let me know how to edit my css to allow bullets?

Comment: There was no doubt this is css that will set lists without bullets. Now, if you are looking for the exact answer/code snippet to allow you to have bullets in your list, then nobody will be able to give you that without a link to your page.

Answer (score 2):

As said in my comment above, nobody can give you an exact answer for your specific problem, without seeing the front-end of your pages, where you want to have the bulleted lists appear.

However, here is something as a starting point:

In your article content, where you are creating your unordered list, you can attach a specific class to your ul element. Something like:

```
<ul class="myBulleted">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item1</li>
</ul>
```

Then in your template's custom css file, you can add:

```
ul.myBulleted, ul.myBulleted li {
    list-style-type:disc !important;
}
```

- Note I am adding !important, since although you have specified the certain selector of your ul, it is still possible that other selectors from your template might take precedence over yours. The !important will give higher precedence to your rules. See yourself, if it is actually needed or not.

#### Update

For this particular case, try adding in your template's custom css file the following:

```
li.workbookcontent.componentheading {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: inherit;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 28px;
    position: relative;
}

li.workbookcontent.componentheading:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    left: 0;
    color: #eb1e00;
    content: "\f14a";
}
```

Since this is a gavick template, usually it comes with an override.css file inside its css folder. You can paste the above code in that file and then you will have to enable the css override from the backend settings of the template.

More info you can obtain from Gavick website: https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla/templates/customization/custom-template-css

On another note, you may want to contact the developers of the template and let them know that although they have added css for creating bullets of unordered lists inside articles, this won't apply, as their css code is looking for a direct ul element after the div.itemBody container, or ul element after another div, and in any case they don't include a ul element after a span which is the actual output.

Actually they have something like this in their typography.css:

```
.itemBody > ul li:before,
.itemBody > div > ul li:before,
ul.gkBullet2 li:before {
    color: #eb1e00;
    content: "\f14a";
}
```

While the html is like:

```
<div class="itemBody">
    <span itemprop="articleBody">
        <ul>
            <li class="workbookcontent componentheading">Select Device &gt; Administrators</li>
            ....
```

Comment: Hi FFrewin, please check out link http://www.keylooplabs.com/index.php/workbooks-2/pan-edu-201/module-1-platforms-and-architecture/add-an-administrator-account

Comment: @Carltonp, so where is the ul you want to appear with bullets?

Comment: Oops. I have added teh bullets now.... http://www.keylooplabs.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&tmpl=component&layout=modal&id=670

Comment: You will see there aren't any bullets on the page but I have added the bullets

Comment: Surely there has to be an easier way, instead of 'adding a specific class'? I wouldn't even know how to do that. All I would like to do is highlight sentences and simply add circle bullets to the sentences.... just like I do in Word.

Comment: Hi, can you also take a look at the following page and again let me know why again I can't see bullets, also can you show me how to change paragraph spacing between sentences please?

Comment: @Carltonp - see update in the answer

Comment: FFrewin, thanks again for getting back to me. There are a number of css files. Is there a particular css  I need to add the code to?

Comment: Can you let me know how to 'enable the css override from the backend settings of the template'? Thanks

Comment: @Carltonp https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla/templates/customization/custom-template-css

Comment: Ok. Great. I've enabled the 'override' I've added the code in the css. How do activate the code on my content?

Comment: I'm trying to add circle black bullets after applying the code suggested above but I'm getting ... http://www.keylooplabs.com/index.php/workbooks-2/pan-edu-201/module-1-platforms-and-architecture/create-new-security-zones

Comment: @Carltonp - You have empty `<li>` tags in your HTML, hence the blank bullets

Comment: I'm trying to create a 'style', that will add component and bullets. Will the following work?li.workbookcontent.componentheading {
    list-style-type:disc !important;
    overflow: inherit;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 28px;
    position: relative;
}

li.workbookcontent.componentheading:before {
    list-style-type:disc !important;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    left: 0;
    color: #eb1e00;
    content: "\f14a";
}