# Red Bullet Points Keep on Appearing

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4, templates

For some reason whenever I create Bullet points, Red tick bullet points keep on appearing. I've obviously made some configuration change to make this happen but I'm not sure where to fix it. The bullets appear on my page here

http://www.keylooplabs.com/index.php/workbooks-2/pan-edu-201/module-8-dycryption/mod8-s2s-9

Can someone let me know where to fix it?

Cheers

Carlton

Comment: You had posted similar question some time ago: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16284/bullets-of-unordered-list-wont-display/16288#16288

Comment: @ffrewin, thanks. I have just checked that out. However, now I have black bullets, but red bullets also appear. I don't see what CSS file I was told to modify...

Answer (score 2):

If you fire-up any Firebug/Inspector, it would quickly tell you to go to `/templates/gk_news2/css/override.css` and on line 19 to edit selector 
`li.workbookcontent.componentheading:before` and disable parameter `content:` and adjust `padding:` to your liking.